# Is there a way to operate on the numbers within brackets in bash?

Tags: bash, perl, unix, awk

I have an input file with some lines of the format -

> *Arbitrary text here {{x1 x2} {x3 x4}} arbitrary text here*

where, x1, x2, x3 and x4 are floats and/or ints. Is there a way to, say, double each of these numbers (always enclosed within curly braces) by using an awk/perl/bash script?

I tried using variants of the following, but I am new to awk, and have not been able to even isolate the number within the curly braces -

> awk -F( '{gsub("{}", " ", $NF); print $NF}'

Example -

Input:

> *Arbitrary text1 here {{1 2} {3 4}} arbitrary text1 here*
>
> *Arbitrary text2 here {{2.0 4} {6.0 8}} arbitrary text2 here*
>
> *Arbitrary text2p5 here*
>
> *Arbitrary text3 here {{3 6} {9 12}} arbitrary text3 here*
>
> *Arbitrary text4 here {{4 8} {12 16}} arbitrary text4 here*

Output:

> *Arbitrary text1 here {{2 4} {6 8}} arbitrary text1 here*
>
> *Arbitrary text2 here {{4.0 8} {12.0 16}} arbitrary text2 here*
>
> *Arbitrary text2p5 here*
>
> *Arbitrary text3 here {{6 12} {18 24}} arbitrary text3 here*
>
> *Arbitrary text4 here {{8 16} {24 32}} arbitrary text4 here*

Comment: Are you looking for something that will find numbers within curly braces which might themselves be nested, and then double each number that's found?  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45155410/edit) your question to show some sample inputs and desired outputs

Comment: Agreed. Yes, it's possible in general, but without a *specific example* of what you want to achieve, this isn't a question that's amenable to good answers.

Comment: Thank you, I added a specific example.

Comment: Your examples are not floats. Those are ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the needed patterns and rewrite the string using their replacements.

Here is a basic approach: capture the components first, process them, then reassemble

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = 'Arbitrary text here {{1 2} {3 4}} arbitrary text here';

my @parts = $str =~ /(.*?){{(\d+) (\d+)} {(\d+) (\d+)}}(.*)/;

# If we expect only lines in the above format test and handle the error
if (@parts != 6) {
    die "Didn't find expected patterns in: $str";
}

my $pre_text  = shift @parts;
my $post_text = pop @parts;

my ($r1, $r2, $r3, $r4) = map { $_*2 } @parts;

my $result = $pre_text . "{{$r1 $r2}{$r3 $r4}}" . $post_text;

print $result, "\n";
```

The code assumes the exact format of input as shown. One advantage of this "manual," step-by-step approach is that it is easier to adjust each part of the process as the need may arise.

---

This can be done in one regex. Since blindly trusting the expected data format is mostly a very bad idea we can put the replacement code in a sub, 
so that matches can be checked and processing more easily adjusted as needed

```
sub repl {
    my @nums = @_;
    die "Expected four numbers, got: @nums" if @nums != 4;

    my ($r1, $r2, $r3, $r4) = map { $_ * 2 } @nums;    

    return "{{$r1 $r2} {$r3 $r4}}";
}

$str =~ s/{{(\d+) (\d+)} {(\d+) (\d+)}}/repl($1, $2, $3, $4)/e;
```

This also considerably cleans up the regex itself.

If the pattern isn't matched then nothing happens and `$str` stays unchanged. If we expect only lines in this format then we may want to know about a failed match. One way to get to know about it is

```
if (not $str =~ s/.../) { warn "Failed match on: $str" }
```

since the substitution operator `s/` returns the number of substituions made.

---

**Update** to provided **input examples**

The single-regex approach above, with a file `input.txt` with lines of input

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'input.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    s/{{(\d+) (\d+)} {(\d+) (\d+)}}/repl($1, $2, $3, $4)/e;
    print;
}

sub repl {
    my @nums = @_; 
    die "Expected four numbers, got: @nums" if @nums != 4;
    my ($r1, $r2, $r3, $r4) = map { $_ * 2 } @nums;    
    return "{{$r1 $r2} {$r3 $r4}}";
}
```

prints

```
Arbitrary text1 here {{2 4} {6 8}} arbitrary text1 here
Arbitrary text2 here {{4 8} {12 16}} arbitrary text2 here
Arbitrary text2p5 here
Arbitrary text3 here {{6 12} {18 24}} arbitrary text3 here
Arbitrary text4 here {{8 16} {24 32}} arbitrary text4 here
```

The line `die ...` in the sub is there merely to protect it in general, perhaps in other uses. In the regex where we use it the sub never gets called unless all four matches were found.

The first approach above, with that code placed in a loop over input lines,  prints the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in Ruby.

```
$ echo "Arbitrary text here {{1.22 -3.55} {6.77 1e66}} arbitrary text here" | 
  ruby -lane 'p $_[/^[^{]*/] << 
                    $_[/{.*}/].gsub!(/[^ {}]+/) {|f| f.to_f*2} <<
                    $_[/[^}]*$/]'
"Arbitrary text here {{2.44 -7.1} {13.54 2.0e+66}} arbitrary text here"
```

In Perl:

```
$ echo "Arbitrary text here {{1.22 -3.55} {6.77 1e66}} arbitrary text here" | 
perl -lane '$lh = $1 if m/(^[^{]*)/; 
            $rh = $1 if m/([^}]*)$/;
            $tgt = $1 if m/(\{.*\})/;
            $tgt =~ s/([^{} ]+)/$1*2/ge;  # the "e" executes the sub as Perl code
            print "$lh$tgt$rh\n";'
Arbitrary text here {{2.44 -7.1} {13.54 2e+66}} arbitrary text here
```

Both approaches here are treating the opening `{` and closing `}` as the start of 'look for a float and do something with it' behavior. There is no parsing for balanced braces for example. Both Perl and Ruby will treat non digits as `0.0` if standalone in this case or the termination of the digits if inside a string of digits:

```
$ echo "Arbitrary text here {{1.22 -3.55 aa} {6s.77 1ye66}} arbitrary text here" | 
perl -lane '$lh = $1 if m/(^[^{]*)/; 
            $rh = $1 if m/([^}]*)$/;
            $tgt = $1 if m/(\{.*\})/;
            $tgt =~ s/([^{} ]+)/$1*2/ge;  # the "e" executes the sub as Perl code
            print "$lh$tgt$rh\n";'
Arbitrary text here {{2.44 -7.1 0} {12 2}} arbitrary text here
```

That may or may not be a feature...

---

With you update. Works great with integers also:

```
$ echo "Arbitrary text1 here {{1 2} {3 4}} arbitrary text1 here
Arbitrary text2 here {{2 4} {6 8}} arbitrary text2 here
Arbitrary text2p5 here
Arbitrary text3 here {{3 6} {9 12}} arbitrary text3 here
Arbitrary text4 here {{4 8} {12 16}} arbitrary text4 here" | 
perl -lane '$rh=$lh=$tgt="";
        $lh = $1 if m/(^[^{]*)/; 
        $rh = $1 if m/([^}]*)$/;
        $tgt = $1 if m/(\{.*\})/;
        $tgt =~ s/([^{} ]+)/$1*2/ge;  # the "e" executes the sub as Perl code
        if ($rh && $lh && $tgt) {
            print "$lh$tgt$rh" ; 
        } else {
            print $_;    
        }'
Arbitrary text1 here {{2 4} {6 8}} arbitrary text1 here
Arbitrary text2 here {{4 8} {12 16}} arbitrary text2 here
Arbitrary text2p5 here
Arbitrary text3 here {{6 12} {18 24}} arbitrary text3 here
Arbitrary text4 here {{8 16} {24 32}} arbitrary text4 here
```